WEB No camera found in nuxt js
I create a project with nuxt 3, and use qr-scanner package, my project run successfully and camera works, but when i shared my project to another device with my (ip and port) camera not working, it shows me (ERROR:No camera found) in another web browser, but I know i give all access in browser and computer, please help me, how i solve that problem
I expected camera open another device

The issue might be that browsers typically only allows camera access when the website is loaded over a secure connection (HTTPS). If you're sharing your project from your local development server (e.g., using a local IP address and port ), it’s likely using an insecure connection (HTTP), and many browsers block camera access on such connections for security reasons.
Try  ngrok http <your-port> – these allow you to share a local development environment over HTTPS.

Yes, be sure of the protocol/URL.
